# How to read and replace Special characters in a fixed length file using shell script

Tags: shell, utf-8, sed

I have a fixed length file in which some records have different special characters like Еӏєпа

I'm able to select those records containing special characters/.

I want to read 2 columns from those records and update it with '*' padded with blanks

Sample Data :

```
1234562013-09-01 01:05:30Еӏєпа   Нцвѡі      A other    
5657812011-05-05 02:34:56abu     jaya       B other
```

Specifically, the 3rd and 4th column containing special characters, should be replaced with  a single '*' padded with blanks to fill the length

I need result like below

```
1234562013-09-01 01:05:30*       *          A2013-09-01 02:03:40other    
5657812011-05-05 02:34:56abu     jaya       B2013-09-01 07:06:10other
```

Tried the following commands :

```
sed -r "s/^(.{56}).{510}/\1$PAD/g;s/^(.{511}).{1023}/\1$PAD/g" errorline.txt  

cut -c 57-568
```

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `awk`, something like:

```
awk '/[LIST__OF_SPECIAL_CHARS]/ {
       l=$0
       # for 3rd col
       # NOTE the * must be padded if you have a fixed length file
       # This can be done with spaces and/or (s)printf, read the docs 
       if (substr($0,FROM,NUM_OF_CHARS) ~ /[LIST__OF_SPECIAL_CHARS]/) {
        l=substr(l,1,START_OF_3RD_COL_MINUS_1) "*" substr(l,START_OF_4TH_COL) 
       } 
       # for 4th col
       # NOTE the * must be padded if you have a fixed length file
       # This can be done with spaces and/or (s)printf, read the docs 
       if (substr($0,START_OF_4TH_COL,NUM_OF_CHARS) ~ /[LIST__OF_SPECIAL_CHARS]/) {
        l=substr(l,1,START_OF_4TH_COL_MINUS_1) "*" substr(l,END_OF_4TH_COL_PLUS_1) 
       }
       # after printing this line, skip to next record.
       print l
       next
     }
     { # prints every other record
       print }' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/.\{56\}.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ].*.\{7\}/ s/\(.\{56\}\).\{20\}\(.\{7\}\)/\1*       *    \2/"errorline.txt
```

where:

- 56 is the first part of your line that don't contain special char
- 20 is the second part taht contain maybe special char
- 7 is the last part, end of your string.
- `"*       *    "` is the string that will replace your special char section.

Adapt those values to your string structure

This sed read all the file and replace only the lines with special char.